# Reading data from NG.L CSV File - Japanese Candlestick Chart

Tags: python-3.x, csv, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I've recently had to physically download a CSV file (NG.L stock) from the Yahoo Finance website as I can no longer pull data from Yahoo directly which I could do no problem with my original financial Python scripts.

My program almost works and displays my NG.L stock chart, but the dates at the bottom of the chart are completely wrong.  They should display only the dates from **02/06/2021** to **09/07/2021** from my NG.L CSV file.

Instead my chart displays dates 23/01/2021 to 19/11/2021 which is very weird.  Is there a quick code fix as I only want the dates to be displayed and extracted from my CSV file.

**NG.L Python code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mpl_dates
import datetime as dt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

# Extracting Data for plotting
data = pd.read_csv('NG.L.csv')
ohlc = data.loc[:, ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', ]]
ohlc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ohlc['Date'])
ohlc['Date'] = ohlc['Date'].apply(mpl_dates.date2num)
ohlc = ohlc.astype(float)

# Creating Subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=0.8, colorup='green', colordown='red', alpha=0.8)

# Setting labels & titles
ax.set_xlabel('TIMELINE of NG.L')
ax.set_ylabel('PRICE IN GBP POUND STERLING')
fig.suptitle('NATIONAL GRID PLC - 2 JUNE 2021 - 9 JULY 2021')

# Formatting Date
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**NG.L Stock Chart:**

[image]

**NG.L CSV file**

[image]

Comment: Please attach your data as a CSV file (not as an image) so that we can reproduce.

Comment: Unfortunately the system won't let me attach the NG.L CSV file.  However, I do have a link from were I got the data originally.   https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/NG.L/history?period1=1622592000&period2=1625788800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true  @Daniel Goldfarb

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the csv file, and copy the above code into a .py file on my machine, and then simply ran it, and got the following result.  Looks fine to me.  What version of mplfinance do you have installed?

[image]

Note also if you look directly at your csv file, in what format are the dates??

```
dino@DINO:~/code/mplfinance/examples/scratch_pad$ head NG.L.csv
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2021-06-01,938.799988,957.755981,938.799988,950.099976,918.291504,5162873
2021-06-02,950.500000,965.599976,948.500000,960.599976,928.439941,9110791
2021-06-03,937.099976,937.099976,909.099976,921.299988,921.299988,9609182
2021-06-04,921.700012,927.799988,912.700012,914.299988,914.299988,7607690
2021-06-07,918.900024,919.229980,913.000000,916.000000,916.000000,5240943
2021-06-08,919.099976,926.200012,914.239990,914.700012,914.700012,12657157
2021-06-09,913.599976,916.299988,909.799988,913.000000,913.000000,6334877
2021-06-10,918.099976,925.000000,911.900024,914.000000,914.000000,7530470
2021-06-11,915.799988,921.809998,914.400024,918.599976,918.599976,8630006
```

---

You may want to consider using the ***new*** mpfinance API.  You can accomplish the same thing with much less code:

```py
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

# Extracting Data for plotting
data = pd.read_csv('NG.L.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

mpf.plot(data,type='candle',style='yahoo',
         ylabel='PRICE IN GBP POUND STERLING',
         title='NATIONAL GRID PLC - 2 JUNE 2021 - 9 JULY 2021',
         datetime_format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

full disclosure: I am the maintainer of the mplfinance library.  For now the old API is remains available via the `from mplfinance.original_flavor` import, for those who are used to it, but I still try to encourage people to use the new API which was designed to be simpler.

Comment: The version of mplfinance I have installed is 0.12.7a17.  If it helps I am also using Python version Conda 3.8 (64-bit).  The compiler I use mostly is called PyScripter (Version 4.0.0.6 x64)

Comment: Good news, I tweaked my NG.L.csv file and only needed to change the date formats from United Kingdom to United States.  Thank you for that hint above relating to the dates.  When I now run my program the Japanese candlesticks and dates are now the way I want them to be displayed.  I didn't need to change my python code in PyScripter, only the CSV file in my folder.  My question has now been answered.  Thank you for helping with this problem @Daniel Goldfarb

Comment: @GrahamBrown I'm glad you were able to get it to work.  Please take a look at my update to the answer and consider using the new API.   All the best.